# Access 2010 macro to set date from checkbox

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database with 2 tables. One table has the boolean field emailed which is just a checkbox on a form now to check off if the client has been emailed.

The second table is called comments. Which has 2 columns, date and details. The date is defaulted to today.

What I am trying to accomplish is for when the checkbox is clicked a date and description of emailed will be added to the comments table.

Do I need a macro to accomplish this? Or is it an event. Also where can I get started to learn about it if it is this.

Comment: are your tables linked in any way?  (ie, is there a foreign key that relates the two?

Comment: Yes they are linked. And if I click the checkbox on the form it is linked with the business.

Comment: Ok... not sure what you mean by "linked with the business".... also not sure what you mean by asking whether it's an event or a macro.   They're not really two distinct things.   A macro is a way to build an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the after update event of the checkbox control to run an append query. You must consider whether the checkbox has been checked or unchecked and decide what to do, for example, if the box is unchecked, does it mean that the email was not sent or just the operator making a mistake. Similarly, if it is checked, is it correcting the mistake or sending another email.